# Import default export ts file in a js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a .ts file that looks like this:

```
// index.ts
import MyModule from './MyModule';
import MyModule2 from './MyModule2';

export default [
  MyModule,
  MyModule2
]
```

I'm trying to import this file in a js file, like so:

```
const modules = require('../../../../entity/index');
```

This works fine locally, but I get the following error in my production environment. What's the issue?
`Error: Cannot find module '../../../../entity/index'`

**edit:**
I changed the import to:

```
const models = require('./../../../../entity/index.ts').default;
```

Now the error is

```
import MyModule from 'MyModule';
^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

which kinda makes sense. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

if you have already specified in your package.json the property

```js
"type": module,
```

try:

```js
import {Mymodule} from 'MyModule.js';
```